# jquery addClass only applied to every second table row

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a table with an jquery onClick event on the tr-rows. I want to highlight the currently selected row. "To highlight" means: change background color and normal font to italic font. So I created a class "selected_row" and in the onClick I'm adding the class to the row. Before, I'm removing the class from all other rows in order to delete highlighting from previously highlighted rows. The thing is that it works fine but only for every second row. This is running in IE8.
I was checking with developer tools in IE8 and while the selected_row class is really applied and visible there for every row with index 1, 3, 5, ... it is *not* applied or visible in the DOM tree in the debugger for rows with index 0, 2, 4, ...
I'm clueless. There is no difference whatsoever between the rows with odd and even index.

Here's part of the code:

```
table th {
    background-color: #ededed; 
    padding: 5px;
}
table td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.selected_row {
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var tableRowClickHandler = function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass ("header")) {
        // alert ('has class');
    }
    else {
        var _this = $(this)
        if (_this.hasClass ("selected_row")) {
            _this.removeClass ("selected_row");
        }
        else { 
            $("tr").each (function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass ("header"))
                $(this).removeClass ("selected_row");
            });
            _this.addClass ("selected_row");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `$('.selected_row').removeClass('selected_row')` to remove all previous occurences of this class

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hkUCJ/1/

Comment: it should be as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hkUCJ/2/

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't seem to work with IE8...

Comment: Could your HTML be malformed? Maybe missing a closing tag somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make this function smaller:

```
var tableRowClickHandler = function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass ("header")) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("tr").removeClass ("selected_row");
        $(this).addClass ("selected_row");
    }
};
```

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1. I extended your jsfiddle example to fit better what I'm actually doing. The table is loaded dynamically and asynchroneously with ajax calls. In a simplified example all works well. Also in my real code the click handler is called, only the $(this).addClass ('selected_row') doesn't have any effect...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not adding the styles through a class but by 2 individual css () calls setting the color and the font-style. This works fine and that is sufficient for me. Don't know why it doesn't work with addClass ().